# How to represent '\am' string in python?

Tags: python, string

I have a problem with '\am' string.

When I am trying to use it I am seeing '\x07m' instead.
[image]

no r'', no '\', etc...

[image]

Comment: Actually in my case, print(r'\am') gives  = \am

Comment: Can you use it in a sentence and post the result you are getting?

Comment: @AmitAmola I need to store it in variable..., not only to repr or print

Comment: Oh okay, got it.
Let me try

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
s = "\\am"
print(s)  # prints \am
len(s)  # returns 3
```

A little explanation. The first backslash is an escape sign, which is no character in itself. It tells the python interpreter that the next character is to be taken literally.

Hence the value of the string `s` will be three characters: `\`, `a` and `m`.

When you type `s`, the console will show you `\\am`. But that does not mean that s is 4 characters long. What happens is that the console prints an escape character before the first character because the first character is `\` which needs escaping.

Comment: Realy! Representing the result of '\\am'' is different than it realy is .

Comment: @gushart Depends on what you mean by *really is*. In a Python string the pair \a means ascii control character 7, which on a teletype used to ring the bell (a is for "alarm"). That in turn is because \ is a string escape character and so needs to be used with care when you mean it literally. In such cases it is nearly always better to use a raw string: r"\am" which doesn't interpret \ in an unexpected way.